# angularjs controller access directive scope value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have this controller with directive inside my html code. The directive have scope value I would like access from the parent controller and show in the html. Hope my example code give you a simple overview of what I'm trying to achieve.

I know this work using $rootScope.showvalue = 'pass text'; in the directive works but don't know if this is the best solution.

```
app.directive('customdir', [function() {
  return {
    restrict:   "E",
    scope:      {    
      showvalue: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      scope.showvalue = 'pass text';

    }
  };  
}]);

app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope) {
  alert($scope.showvalue); 
});



<html>
     <div ng-controller="mycontroller">
        <custom-dir></custom-dir>

           /* Show scope value from custom dir */

          {{showvalue}}
     </div>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're binding the directive's isolate scope `showvalue` property via *bidirectional binding*, you can simple pass the parent scope property in as an attribute

```
<customdir showvalue="showvalue"></customdir>

<p>{{showvalue}}</p>
```

Demo ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/W5k0hgDElklseOvjwRsS?p=preview

---

If you want the HTML to be `<custom-dir>`, you'll need to rename your directive to `'customDir'`.

Comment: For some reason only $rootScope.showvalue = 'pass text'; works. Maybe because the controller and directive are in 2 separate files

Comment: Did you look at the demo? It clearly works. Separating the files makes no difference

Comment: Yes, your demo works fine clear example. Just my code its not working. I think maybe how the controller is setup.

Comment: Got it working now. The previous developer was using var crtlName = this; So to make it work I had to use {{crltName.somevalue}}. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pass "showvalue" to the directive via attributes.
2. You can set value through $parent property of directive scope. eg. scope.$parent.showvalue = 'pass text';
3. You can use emit event to pass data from child (directive) to parent (controller).
4. You can directly set value to the controller scope using shared scope. (Do not specify scope property in directive)